# Query subset of Firebase (NoSQL) data

Tags: firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firebase (NoSQL) collection of say 5,000 "players". Each day I want to query a subset of those players in order to perform some operation. My question is, what is the best way to do that?

As best as I can tell, there is no way to perform such a query within Firebase directly. So for example, I cannot say "Collection of 5,000 players, give me all of the players which match ANY of these identifiers". If that *is* an option, please advise.

One option I thought of would be to create a *new* collection each day with the identifiers of players I am interested in performing operations on. Would this be the preferred method in Firebase? IE, I'd create a collection like `20190105Game` and it would contain the identifier subset. I'd query that collection first, then go to the `Players` collection to get `collection.where("identifier", "==", "other_identifier")`

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to filter a subset of the players, you have two options:

1. Include the condition for the subset into your query. E.g. `playersRef.where("subset", "=", 2).where("othercondition", "=", "value").orderBy("somefield").limit(2)`
2. Create a (sub)collection for the subset of players.

Neither is pertinently better than the other, it all depends on your exact use-cases. I'd typically go for the first option, unless I have a use-case where tht is impossible due to my other query or throughput requirements.

Comment: Interesting. So my use case is the collection of players is basically never going to change. Each day however, the players I want from that collection to perform my operation _will_ change. It feels like creating a new collection is the best route, I just wasn't sure if that was less than ideal. Seems fine?